# FastAPI - Pydantic Query Parameter with Enum

Tags: python, fastapi, pydantic

#### Problem

I am unable to use Pydantic model as a query parameter and to support things like enum, it doesn't work. You can do a hacky way to use Pydantic for query parameters with `Depends` but it doesn't work as well as it should.

This is a very big requirement in our company and I'm guessing that a lot of other companies use the query parameters as well.

[image]

#### Looking for solution like this

[image]

##### Additional

I would like to use Pydantic models as a Query Parameter natively without the `Depends` does anyone have an idea how to do it?

Comment: @Chris Yes, this does it. Ok the Option 2 looks much more pythonic. Post it and I will accept the answer.